# ng-repeat is not refreshed when ng-click method called from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on creating reusable directive which will be showing composite hierarchical data .

On first page load, Categories like "Server" / "Software"/ "Motherboard" (items array bound to ng-repeat) would be displayed . If user clicks on "Server" then it would show available servers like "Ser1"/"Ser2"/"Ser3".

```
 html : 

        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="init()">
         <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="item in items">
               <div my-dir paramitem="item"></div>
                </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Now first time Items are loading, but clicking on any item is not refreshing ng-repeat. I have checked ng-click, "subItemClick" in below controller, method and it is being fired. However the items collection is not getting refreshed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rZk9cbEJU90oupVgcSQt

```
    Controller: 

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.init = function() {
          $scope.items = [{iname: 'server',subItems: ['ser1', 'ser2','ser3']}
          ];
        };

        $scope.subItemClick = function(sb) {
          if (sb.subItems.length > 0) {
            var zdupitems = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < sb.subItems.length; i++) {
              zdupitems.push({
                iname: sb.subItems[i],
                subItems: []               
              });
            }
            $scope.items = zdupitems; 
    }
        };

      }])
      .directive('myDir', function() {
        return {
          controller: 'myCtrl',
          template: "<div><a href=# ng-click='subItemClick(paramitem)'>{{paramitem.iname}}</a></div>",
          scope: {
            paramitem: '='
          }
            }
      });
```

I am expecting items like ser1/ser2 to be bound to ng-repeat on clicking "Server" but it is not happening .

Any help?

Comment: your directive uses isolated scope. There is no `subItemClick()` available in that scope until you pass it in

Answer (score 0):

I think that onClick is screwing up the method's definition of $scope. In that context, the $scope that renders the ngRepeat is actually $scope.$parent (do not use $scope.$parent), and you're creating a new `items` array on the wrong $scope.

I realize the jsfiddle is probably a dumbed down example of what you're dealing with, but it's the wrong approach either way. If you need to use a global value, you should be getting it from an injected Service so that if one component resets a value that new value is reflected everywhere. *Or* you could just not put that onClick element in a separate Directive. What's the value in that?